# Error when matching backslash ( \ ) from clipboard

Tags: java, regex, clipboard, backslash

I have a the following code:

```
try {
    String clipStrg = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
        .getSystemClipboard()
        .getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

    if ("Test I want to match".matches(clipStrg))
    {
        System.out.println(clipStrg);
    }

    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Toolframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

When I have a backslash (`"\"`) in the clipboard, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: The .matches() method of String is a regular expression match. You want to use the .equals() method, not .matches()

Comment: The string is not case sensitive, that is why I want to use .matches() and not .equals().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape or quote your pattern, as the back-slash is a control character for regex.

For instance:

```
if ("Test I want to match".matches(Pattern.quote(clipStrg)))
```

If you're just comparing `String`s, use `equals` instead:

```
if ("Test I want to match".equals(clipStrg))
```

Comment: So I need to escape the pattern from the clipboard as well?

Comment: @uranibaba you need to quote/escape the `String` only when you interpret it as a `Pattern`, which turns out to be happening when you invoke `String.matches`.